# homework help? for making a spirograph

Tags: python

SO over break week our teacher gave us a little project to do requiring a Spirograph, here is the code he helped us write before

```
from graphics import *
from math import *

def ar(a):
    return a*3.141592654/180

def main():
    x0 = 100
    y0 = 100
    startangle = 60
    stepangle = 120
    radius = 50

    win = GraphWin()

    p1 = Point(x0 + radius * cos(ar(startangle)), y0 + radius * sin(ar(startangle)))

    for i in range(stepangle+startangle,360+stepangle+startangle,stepangle):
        p2 = Point(x0 + radius * cos(ar(i)), y0 + radius * sin(ar(i)))
        Line(p1,p2).draw(win)
        p1 = p2

    input("<ENTER> to quit...")
    win.close()

main()
```

he then wants us to develop the program that consecutively draws 12 equilateral triangles (rotating the triangle each time by 30 degrees through a full 360 circle).  This can be achieved by “stepping” the STARTANGLE parameter. My question I am stuck on where to go from here, what does he mean by "stepping?" I assume making some sort of loop, is it possible someone can give me a push in the right step?

Comment: My guess (and since I'm only guessing here, this is a comment and not an answer) is that he's talking about using the `step` value of `range`, as he does in the example code. In case you're unaware, range works as: `range(start,stop,step)`, starting at `start`, ending one before `stop`, and moving `step` distance each time.

Comment: I suggest you read adsmith's comment here, and then try to fiddle with the parameters to get a feel of what's happening. Although this code will draw a polygon, not a triangle. You would have to draw some lines to the origin also.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled as to why your teacher would have you import everything from `math`... but then not use `pi`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using matplotlib. The general procedure would be the same. But you will have to modify it for using the libraries you're allowed to use.

```
from math import radians, sin, cos 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

startAngle = 0 
stepAngle = 30
origin = (0,0)

points = []
points.append(origin)
points.append((cos(radians(startAngle)), sin(radians(startAngle))))

for i in range(startAngle + stepAngle, 360 + stepAngle, stepAngle):
    x = cos(radians(i))
    y = sin(radians(i))
    points.append((x,y))
    points.append(origin)
    points.append((x,y))

x,y = zip(*points) #separate the tupples into x and y coordinates. 

plt.plot(x,y) #plots the points, drawing lines between each point
plt.show()
```

`plt.plot` draw lines between each point in the list. We're adding inn the origin points so we get triangles instead of just a polygon around the center. [image]